# Parallelization & processing of ppm() in spatstat?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, spatial, spatstat

I am attempting to fit a point pattern with **`ppm()`** in `spatstat`, version 1.60-1, using a combination of first-order covariates (as im objects) and a second-order interaction term, in this case an Area-Interaction model.

For my data, comprising: ~300 points, 3 covariate im.objects of ~110 MB each, and the area interaction term at **`r = 15000`** map units (meters), processing time is proving to be **prohibitively long - over 72 hours** at this point.

Using some of the data included in **`spatstat`** itself:

```
require(spatstat)
res <- vector()

for (i in seq(1, 9, 0.5)) {
    start.time <- Sys.time()
    ppm(swedishpines, ~1, AreaInter(r=i))
    end.time <- Sys.time()
    time.taken <- end.time - start.time
    res[i] <- time.taken
}

plot(res)
```

### Output:

[image: Output Graph]

it can be seen that the processing time increases roughly linearly. I imagine that the size of the point pattern, window, inclusion of covariates, and apparently most importantly, the value of **`r`**, heavily affect this too.

My reason for believing this is that I previously ran `ppm()` with a larger point pattern, similar covariates, but a much smaller value of `r` (~7000 instead of ~15000)

It appears to be relatively simple to parallelize the `envelope()` function and pool the results with the corresponding function, but I am looking for advice on how to parallelize `ppm()` and be able to combine the output fitted models? There doesn't seem to be a direct implementation of this task for ppm objects.

Alternatively, if someone is more familiar with the implementation of the Area Interaction model in `spatstat`, I'd be grateful to know if I am just chasing cars with such a large value of `r`, and if I would be better off trying a different approach.

Comment: 72 hours on what kind of hardware?

Comment: This is just on my home machine, running on an old i5-3570K quad core with 8 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

In the above code, you are selecting the value of the disc radius parameter `r` by making repeated calls to `ppm` in a loop. This is wasteful, because information is re-computed each time. It would be much faster to use the `spatstat` function `profilepl` which is designed for this purpose. It uses efficient shortcuts, including special tricks for the area interaction model.

The area-interaction model is not a second order interaction; it has infinite order. It is therefore quite complicated to compute.

Another strategy for selecting `r` would be to temporarily replace the area interaction by the `Penttinen` interaction, a second order interaction, which is close to the area interaction. Being a second order interaction the Penttinen model can be fitted very quickly so you can rapidly determine a good value for `r`.

The development of faster algorithms for `AreaInter` is on our list of things to do. But no-one is funding us for this..

Comment: I considered the Pentinnen interaction, but shied away as I wasn't sure the extent to which it was comparable to AreaInter. Good to know it can be substituted here.

I eventually want to pass the fitted model to `envelope()` to assess goodness of fit (any further divergence from the critical envelope at ranges above or below `r = 15000` I will tackle in discourse).

Comment: Thank you! Superfast - for 1034 points on 1km² area it took 1 second, for the profiling about 10 seconds for 60 models. AreaInteraction does not seem to end before next week.